# Flex vertical alignment issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I had a row of inline-block elements which wrapped nicely on a new line if did not fit:

[image: vertically aligned inline-block elements]

```css
.buttons div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="buttons">
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div>Some text here</div>
    <div><span></span>Some text here</div>    
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle link #1](https://jsfiddle.net/hendricson/knb554rk/2/)

Now I'm changing the layout to flex like that:

```css
.buttons div {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

And the elements are not longer vertically aligned:

[image: inline-flex elements are not longer vertically aligned]

[JSFiddle link #2](https://jsfiddle.net/hendricson/knb554rk/3/)

How to get the row of div elements shown in the HTML snippet above to look like on my first image, but with flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a *flex formatting context* with `display: inline-flex` you need to reset the `vertical-align` property. Add this to your code:

```
.buttons div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.buttons div {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  vertical-align: top;  /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
</div>
```

The default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline`. Because some of your flex containers have a single *anonymous flex item* (the text) while others have an *anonymous flex item* and a `span`, this is apparently generating two different baselines for the parent. By changing the `vertical-align` value to `top`, `middle`, `bottom` or something else the problem should be solved.

Alternatively, if using `display: inline-flex` is not essential, a better solution is to simply apply `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` to the primary container.

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.buttons div {
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
  <div>Some text here</div>
  <div><span></span>Some text here</div>
</div>
```

This will eliminate the `vertical-align` issue altogether.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, Michael!

Answer (score 2):

display: flex should actually be a property of the container, not the items in the flexbox. You will also need to set some other properties to get the same behavior as the original.

```
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

// Remove display property from .buttons div
```

[More info](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Michael_B While this is technically valid CSS, it's still bad because flexbox isn't actually being utilized. Flexbox controls how child elements wrap and scale within the container (the element with display: flex). In the OP, the divs are considered the containers, and flexbox is controlling the children of the divs, when .buttons is what really should have been the container.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is incorrect, and it does work to solve the problem. I just figured the OP might want to know why there is an alignment difference between *inline-block* and *inline-flex*.

Answer (score 2):

This should help
http://codepen.io/flurrd/pen/dvwpPp

```
 <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn">Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn"><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn">Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn"><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn">Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn"><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn">Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn"><span></span>Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn">Some text here</div>
    <div class="btn"><span></span>Some text here</div> 
</div>

.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.btn {
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: 0.3em; 
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```